# I deleted TOR browser but the name is still showing in app draw (only name) , if i try to open it doesnt

Tags: tor

I deleted TOR browser but the name is still showing in app draw (only name) , if i try to open it doesnt opens. Please Help me with this!! its really annoying. please reply

[image: here is the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you installed the browser.

Most likely you can remove the `.desktop` file from `~/.local/share/applications`.